# Wireless network randomly disappears with router DLink DSL-2730U

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

I have a wireless ADSL router DLink DSL-2730U. Everything works fine except that the wireless network sometimes disappears randomly. When the network disappears I also see a network with SSID DLink_DWR-116 that appears with almost no signal strength. This network only appears when my configured network disappears and I am almost positive that this is not a weak signal from a neighbors router. This symptom is on Ubuntu 16.04 as well as from my Android phone. A Windows 8 laptop almost always fails to connect to the network even when the network is visible.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Thanks Ron for pointing that out. Is there some way to move the question to the right SE site?

Answer (score 2):

The Wi-Fi receiver on your computer is constantly measuring:

- desired signal strength
- noise signal strength

Using tools like LinSSID you can monitor the WiFi performance. In most cases signal and noise will be negative numbers. This is because the measurement of the wireless signal in watts is converted to a logarithmic ratio unit (dBm). 
So if signal power is grater than 1 milliwatt, dBm value will be positive else negative. 
Generally the signal measurement will be between around -10 and -70 dBm, and  the noise between -80 to -100 dBm.

**What you can do**

So,

To know if the channel you are using is busy, you can use software like:

- LinSSID (or others);

that are free tools for Ubuntu Linux and helps you to understand if there is a problem with your wireless network.

- Most home wireless routers are set up to change channel automatically (default configuration). Setting a static channel is not a good idea on environments where you cannot control every wireless device.
- Change source position
- Increase the radio power (if it's low)
- Remove obstructions (some kind of objects (i.e metal) can degrade the quality of the signal). Common obstructions are Cabinets or drawers, Mirrors, Glasses, Metal Objects,Thick walls and ceilings, Aquariums
- (If automatic procedure don't do it) force the channel to change to one is more free

The most important thing is the signal-to-noise ratio. 
Data corruption and therefore re-transmissions will occur if the received signal is too close to the noise floor.

Example: a received signal of -65 dBm can be considered good at location that has a noise floor of -90 dBm (SNR 25 dB) but not so much at a location with a noise floor of -80 dBm (SNR 15 dB). [Cisco Meraki Documentation example]

Generally, a signal with an SNR value of 20 dB or more is recommended for data networks.

So, more distance there is between signal and noise floor better is for your wifi network.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have changed to static channels, radio power was already set to 100%, no control over obstructions, source limited by desktop computer set up connected to the router. Signal strength is -59dBm but not able to find noise level in iwconfig.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a result of interference with another network which uses the same channel.

To remedy this, log in to your router's management page and try to change the channel to something else, preferably 1, 6 or 13 (might not be available in all routers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When the router is behaving well I am usually not able to find any other wireless networks in range. So not sure if it is due to interference. I have anyway set the router to operate in a fixed channel.